# Index out of range error occurs even when the iterator is way far away from the min and max bounds of array

Tags: arrays, swift

Sorry everyone, may be a redundant question. But ,i am posting this question after straining my brain for like 4 hours of debugging and googling this issue on many stack overflow threads.

As the terminal debugger shows:

- The sentences array size or count is 519554
- The error occurs exactly at the iterator count of 312891
- You can also see in the terminal, there is no issue accessing the
  indexes 312892 or 312891. The data is there. I am able to print them
  out. I cannot figure out my mistake    here. Please help me fix this..

[image]

Comment: You might want to check the count of the components of the sentence before accessing the element at index 2 there, to not let your code crash through invalid data. What I want to say with that is, that the access of sentences[index] is fine, but the second access to the separated components might not be fine.

Comment: Also: the 't' in the console when you print out no. 312892 looks different than the other 't's printed out in the console, might be the reason.

Comment: You are my saviour. Just removed that 't' in the data and added a tab myself in the data source file at that line and it seems to work now. I don't know what formatting issue happened there, but thanks for the pointer . It seems like I need to add some more checks and do some data cleaning.
Can you please post your comment as answer? I will mark it as the solution. Thanks :)

Comment: Glad I could help you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue might not be the access of the `sentences` with the `index` but the other array access where you take the element at index of the separated sentence. You might want to add a check there, so an invalid data format doesn't crash your code and you can perform some error handling/analysis. You also can see one '\t' for the printed out sentence at index 312892 is different from the other 't's printed out in the console, so that it makes sense that it crashes there as the sentence separated by "\t" only contains two elements instead three.